# wrong timezone when loading joda Instant field via JPA

Tags: jpa, playframework, jodatime

In my Play application I have a model with a `created` field of type `Instant`. It's populated using a `@PrePersist` hook which just sets it to a `new Instant()`. The default timezone is correctly detected as `US/Chicago`, and when persisted to mysql it appears in the same timezone (in a `datetime` field).

However, when the object is read back from the database and the time is displayed, it's shown in UTC rather than local time. I'm currently displaying it using

```
${org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forStyle("SS").printTo(out, object.created)}
```

Being new to Joda and fairly new with JPA, I'm not sure if this is a joda problem, a JPA problem, if I should be using a different Joda type, a different mysql type, or if I'm going about this completely wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you try setting the default timezone for play? Something like "-Duser.timezone=US/Chicago" as an extra VM argument.

Comment: @seb can that be done when running with the `play` command? And would it make any difference if it's already detecting the right time zone?

Comment: Yes you can append that after any play command. Missed the part about default timezone correctly detected, will write a proper answer in a second

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) UTC seems to be the reference timezone. You can always change that on the [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) itself with the `withZone(DateTimeZone)` method. The following code outputs the date in America/Chicago which seems to be the [right timezone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) in joda-zime:

```
${org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forStyle("SS").withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago")).printTo(out, object.created)}
```

Following the [user guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#TimeZones) you can also set the default timezone for joda with `DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));` but I always thought that specifing the default timezone with an VM argument works too and should be the better option.